# Why does Apple Xcode iOS Simulator lose the Safari.app?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, safari, ios-simulator

I'm using Apple's Xcode iOS-Simulator to run tests of a **browser application** on a (virtual) iPad device. To connect my code I use Appium.
But sometimes the iOS simulator **loses the safari.app**, so I can't run the tests (without a browser on my device - it's not only not displayed, it's not there). I **don't know why** the safari.app is lost and when this happens. It's the same problem with all devices (iPad and iPhone) and all software versions that are installed.

First, I tried "*reset content and settings*", but nothing happened. Then I installed Xcode's iOS-Simulator 6.1 package and switched to it. This version contained safari.app. I switched through the different versions and after some switches, the devices with 7.1 had safari.app again.

A short time later Xcode iOS-Simulator lost the app again. "*Reset content and settings*" didn't work again, switching the versions had this time no effect.

Then, I removed Xcode from the mac and installed it again (with 2.1 gb to download...). safari.app was not on the simulated device. I used "*reset content and settings*" and then the safari.app was there.

The last part (from reinstall to reset) is the way I go every time the simulator loses safari.app, which wastes time and is annoying!

I use OS X 10.9.2 with Xcode 5.1.1 (Build 5B108).

So I have two questions:

1. What causes iOS-Simulator to lose safari.app?
2. How can I get it back without reinstalling Xcode?

Comment: Same problem for me, any simpler solutions out there?

Comment: Same problem here since few days. I think it is due to lasts updates.

Comment: I lost Safari app on my iOS Simulator after I downloaded another version of XCode (now I have 2 versions - XCode 6.1 and XCode 4.6.3) on my machine. Did you find a solution to retain iOS Simulator between XCode updates? Resetting content and settings works for iOS6.1 but interestingly, it did not do anything for latter versions like iOS 8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a workaround. You are able to open the xcode folder and go to your simulation files. Do a backup of the ios-Simulator files. If your simulator loses the safari app, close xcode and copy your backup files into your xcode folder again. So you don't have to reinstall it.